# Automatic Report Generation of Aggregated Data over the last hour

Tags: sql-server, bigdata, aggregate, data-warehouse, polling

I have several devices which periodically measures (e.g. every second) many physical values like pressure, temperature, energy consumption, current, voltage….

Every value is sent to a server and stored in a database table. The table contains millions of rows and each row contains measurement information like DeviceId – Timestamp – Value

Every second, about 1000 new measurement entries are inserted into the table.

I try to introduce a processing layer, where I can define hundreds of status reports on certain devices to be created hourly (e.g. HourlyConsumptionReportOfDevice1Device2), where I write down aggregated values of the device measurements over the last hour.

I tried to poll the huge table each minute to see if there are already present values for Device1 and Device2 over the last hour but this induces poor results, especially when crating reports for 20+ devices

Basically, I am searching for a way to trigger an action for report generation as soon as one hour has passed AND all the values of the affected devices are available in the huge table. Due to network latency, certain devices may “send” the value for 16:00 at 16:01 thus delaying the report generation for one minute.

Can anyone please give me some hint, on how to achieve this and can possible recommend some literature…

I’m not even quite sure on which fields I should extend my research efforts, e.g. Data warehousing, ETL?? Any recommendations are welcome

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: There are many articles describing how RRDtool (Round Robin Database tool) works for time series data. You may even choose to switch to it instead of reinventing the wheel.